# Print to an Ubuntu Printer that is not supported by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, remote

I have an HP Laserjet 1000 that is working fine in Ubuntu 12.04 and is shared but there is no driver for Windows 7. Is it possible to create a wrapper for it, maybe with something like GhostScript to present it as a different printer when shared so I can user it remotely?

Comment: You're looking for Samba printer sharing. http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-and-Windows-Shared-Printing/sharing_with_windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this tip for Vista which should work in Windows 7.

> All you need to do is to download the Windows XP driver file for HP laserJet 1000 from HP website. It's the one named HP LaserJet 1000 Host Based Driver
>
> 1. Right click and unzip the .exe file you've just downloaded
> 2. Go to Printers (Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Printers)
> 3. Right click anywhere in the window and select Add a printer. The popup window should now appear
> 4. Click Add a local printer
> 5. Click Next
> 6. Click Have Disk
> 7. Browse to the location of unzipped folder you (See step 1)
> 8. My printer was with USB so I choose zUSB.inf (not sure about serial, u might have to choose HPLJ1000 for serial)
> 9. Click Open and then OK
>
> Computer will install the printer named HP LaserJet 1000, but it won't work.
>
> Now Connect your printer to the computer. Vista will look for the printer driver and install the printer which will work. You should now delete the printer named "HP LaserJet 1000" and make "HP LaserJet 1000 (Copy)" the default printer. You might want to rename it too.

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistaprinting/thread/90bbd29f-6ab8-4192-8bbc-923558781cb5

Comment: I am on 64-bit and the HP site no longer allows for the download of Vista and Windows 7 drivers. They are only available via windows update which does not allow the download of an alternate driver.